# Biblioteca pg vs pg-promise

Tags: node.js

No meu projeto utilizei a biblioteca `pg` para acesso ao banco postgres. Porém com algumas necessidades, utilizei a biblioteca `pg-promise`. Para quem ja utilizou ambas, e entende mais sobre o assunto, gostaria de saber qual é a mais indica para acesso ao postgres.

Comment: A diferênça é uma questão de estilo. Se preferes usar callbacks "à moda antiga" ou Promises.

Comment: Então a biblioteca `pg-promise` pode ser considerada uma biblioteca confiável ? @Sergio

Comment: Parece-me que sim: https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise está muito ativa e tem releases frequentemente.

Comment: Muito Obrigado @Sergio